# Mappedsuperclass and namedqueries

Tags: java, jpa

I have a mappedsuperclass like this :

```
@MappedSuperclass
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "USER_TYPE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "selectAllUsers", query = "SELECT u FROM User u"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "deleteUserByName", query = "DELETE FROM User u WHERE u.userName like :name"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "getUserByName", query = "SELECT FROM User u WHERE u.userName like :name") })
public abstract class User implements Serializable {....
```

I get a ***"The abstract schema type 'User' is unknown"*** error on the namedquery.  I don't understand why ... the name User is right?

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected JPA behaviour. Mapped superclasses are not queryable (see JPA 2.0 spec, section
2.11.2). If you want to make a superclass queryable, change the annotation from `@MappedSuperclass` to `@Entity`.

Comment: Ok thx, I made the class a mappedsuperclass because I only want the extended classes to be persisted. I then wanted to retrieve them as supertype and look what "type" they where by use of a named query ...

Comment: @DarthBlueRay The only difference between the two annotations in this case is that mapped superclasses are not queryable, while entities are. This has no impact on the mapping whatsoever. There is no facility in JPA to make a class queryable but not persistable.

Comment: Also, mapped super classes cannot be part of a relationship.